# .htaccess URL Cloaking?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess on Apache, is it possible to have the web browser address bar display www.website.com/anypage.php when the page actually resides at www2.website.com:123/anypage.php

(anypage.php could be anything, or even another directory)

Comment: Yes, that is possible, _if_ you have administrative access to the configuration of the website.com http server and can use the rewriting module there. Check the documentation, it is very well explained.

Comment: Yes I do have administrative access as the whole LAMP is on my computer. But do I use mod_rewrite or what?

Comment: With "rewriting module" I referred to "mod_rewrite", so yes.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "actually resides". A web server is software that responds to requests for URLs with some content, that content doesn't necessarily have a "real" URL. If the question is how to serve content which is from another server, or a different piece of software, then proxying is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with the proxy system `mod_rewrite` uses, but this should do the trick for you:

Place the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www2.website.com:123/$1 [P]
```

This will proxy *all* requests made to `website.com` to `www2.website.com:123`.

**Note:** [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) must be enabled in order to use this flag.

For further information, please [read the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) on the Proxy Flag.